# Как избежать бесконечного цикла

Tags: android, kotlin

Пытаюсь написать динамический конвертер величин (Inch/km) т.е. хочу чтобы между полями editText и editText2 была связь и значения менялись в реальном времени без нажатия лишних кнопок.
Написал обработку через TextWatcher, но там очевидно процесс зацикливается потому что поля заменяют сами себя и в итоге устройство виснет.
Я чувствую, что проблема детская, но буду благодарен если вы подскажите как избежать зацикливания и мб подкинете какие нибудь ресурсы (желательно сразу по Kotlin) почитать. Спасибо.

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)


    editText.addTextChangedListener(object : TextWatcher {
        override fun afterTextChanged(p0: Editable?) {
        }
        override fun beforeTextChanged(p0: CharSequence?, p1: Int, p2: Int, p3: Int) {
        }
        override fun onTextChanged(p0: CharSequence?, p1: Int, p2: Int, p3: Int) {
            try {
                editText2.setText("${editText.text.toString().toFloat() / 39370}")
               status.text = ""
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                status.text = "error" }
        }
    })

    editText2.addTextChangedListener(object : TextWatcher {
        override fun afterTextChanged(p0: Editable?) {
        }
        override fun beforeTextChanged(p0: CharSequence?, p1: Int, p2: Int, p3: Int) {
        }
        override fun onTextChanged(p0: CharSequence?, p1: Int, p2: Int, p3: Int) {
            try {
                editText.setText("${editText2.text.toString().toFloat() * 39370}")
               status.text = ""
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                status.text = "error"}
        }
    })


}
```

[image: Внешний вид]

Comment: Попробуйте сделать асинхронную проверку каждого из значений. Две переменные хранят старые значения. Каждые пол секунды сверяем их с тем, что в текстовых полях. Если одно из полей изменилось - вычисляем второе и суем значение в соответствующее поле и заменям значения в переменных для "старых" значений.

Comment: Асинхронная - в плане, что проверка должна идти асинхронно от основного процесса (ввода)

Comment: @AnonimYs очень интересное предложение, а вы могли дать ссылку на литературу по этой теме?

Comment: Если честно, я в этом не силен. Но знаю, что прям по этой теме - "корутины". Это вроде как функции, которые сами по себе выполняются полностью асинхронно, но не создают новые потоки (не нагружают систему), а так же могут быть остановлены на паузу. Или не функции, не уверен, но работают эти корутины именно так.

Answer (score 0):

Предлагаю такой вариант на Java (Ещё не знаком с Kotlin)

```
final EditText txt1 = findViewById(R.id.txt1);
    final EditText txt2 = findViewById(R.id.txt2);

    final TextWatcher txt1W = new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            txt2.setText(txt1.getText());
        }
    };

    final TextWatcher txt2W = new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            txt1.setText(txt2.getText());
        }
    };



    txt1.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View view, boolean hasFocus) {
            if (hasFocus) {

               txt1.addTextChangedListener(txt1W);


            } else {


                txt1.removeTextChangedListener(txt1W);
            }
        }
    });



    txt2.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View view, boolean hasFocus) {
            if (hasFocus) {

                txt2.addTextChangedListener(txt2W);


            } else {


                txt2.removeTextChangedListener(txt2W);
            }
        }
    });
```

**Простыми словами можно дополнительно прослушивать фокусировку и в зависимости от этого добавлять и удалять прослушку изменений текста.**

Answer (score 0):

Решил проблему через установку фокуса. Получается тело под полем ввода запускается только когда мы его касаемся и игнорирует изменения своего состояния пока его не трогают.

```
override fun onTextChanged(p0: CharSequence?, p1: Int, p2: Int, p3: Int) {
          var v:View = currentFocus 
            if (v == editText) {
            b = true
                try {
                  f = editText.text.toString().toFloat()
                    status.text = ""
                } catch (e:Exception) {b = false}
                if (b) {
                    f = f / 39370; editText2.setText(f.toString(),TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE) } else
                    status.text = "error"
            }
        }
```